# Can't add group attribute via Keycloak Admin Rest API

Tags: keycloak

I'm sending a request to `PUT /{realm}/groups/{id}` to add a group attribute to an existing group.

The body of PUT request looks like this:

```
{"attributes":{"id":123}}
```

It's failing and returning 500 error.

The documentation is not clear about the format of "Map" schema. https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/6.0/rest-api/#_grouprepresentation shows "attributes" field type is "Map" but it's not defined. I tried several formats, like:

```
{"attributes":[{"id":123}]}
{"attributes":{"key":"id","value":123}}
{"attributes":[{"key":"id","value":123}]}
```

but none of them is working.

What is "Map" schema and why is my request returning 500?

Comment: I totally agree with you, the REST API admin docs are not documented properly which increases our development time by a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create group along with attribute, request body will be

```
{"name":"myGroup","attributes":{"attr1":["value1"]}}
```

with two attributes it should be something like this

```
{"name":"mygroup","attributes":{"attr2":["value2"],"attr1":["value1"]}}"
```